# class template's constructor declaration doesn't compile for C++20 but compiles for C++17

Tags: c++, c++17, language-lawyer, c++20, class-template

I am learning about templates in C++. In particular, i saw [here](https://youtu.be/LMP_sxOaz6g?list=PLpHxZMy35Lo1255K3eSmjd161ra4vSnFT&t=1519) that we can have the following declaration for the constructor:

```
template<typename T>
struct Rational
{
  Rational<T>();  
};
```

But the above snippet [fails](https://wandbox.org/permlink/ZuECouLNMdUUycGS) to compile in C++2a and [compiles successfully](https://wandbox.org/permlink/Jh65Ht3uoUShMMgp) for C++17.

Is this a compiler bug or there is a reason why it doesn't compile for C++2a and C++2b. If there is a reason then what is it. I want to know *which clauses(if any) from the standard allow/prevent the following examples to compile*. Since i have tested the above example with C++17 and C++20 so i am looking for citation from only these two standard versions.

Comment: @bobah At the beginning of my question, i have mentioned the [source](https://youtu.be/LMP_sxOaz6g?list=PLpHxZMy35Lo1255K3eSmjd161ra4vSnFT&t=1519) from where this example is. And i don't think they will make this mistake or at least they would tell us about the mistake. Please take a look at the given link? Also, your suggestion of replacing `Rational<T>();` with `Rational();` seems pointless because they both are equivalent according to the given link.

Comment: @bobah It's not a bug in C++17's compiler. Its valid to use `Rational<T>();` in C++17 and is equivalent to writing `Rational();` according to the given [source](https://youtu.be/LMP_sxOaz6g?list=PLpHxZMy35Lo1255K3eSmjd161ra4vSnFT&t=1519).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is not a bug.

It is the consequence of a [change](http://eel.is/c++draft/diff.cpp17.class#2) in the standard.

> Affected subclauses: [class.ctor] and [class.dtor]
> Change: A simple-template-id is no longer valid as the declarator-id of a constructor or destructor.
> Rationale: Remove potentially error-prone option for redundancy.
> Effect on original feature: Valid C++ 2017 code may fail to compile in this revision of C++. For example:

```
template<class T>
struct A {
  A<T>();           // error: simple-template-id not allowed for constructor
  A(int);           // OK, injected-class-name used
  ~A<T>();          // error: simple-template-id not allowed for destructor
};
```

There is however a [bug report](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=97202), that was initially closed and then reopen with the intention of improving the diagnostics message.

Comment: So this means that `Rational<T>();` is valid in C++11, C++14 and C++17 but not in C++20 & onwards, right?

Comment: Yes, that is my understanding.

Answer (score 2):

> Is this a compiler bug or there is a reason why it doesn't compile for
> C++2a and C++2b.

Yes, this is a GCC *diagnostic*  bug that has existed since 2020, see [PR 97202](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=97202#c6).

Quoted from [Marek Polacek](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=97202#c2), one of the GCC contributors

> This is C++20 [DR 2237](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_defects.html), disallow simple-template-id in cdtor: see
> [[diff.cpp17.class]](https://eel.is/c++draft/diff.cpp17#class-2) p2.  Just the diagnostic we give is horrible ;(.

That said, this is the expected behavior with the implementation of DR2237, it's just that diagnostic is a bit bad.

Comment: So is using `Rational<T>();` valid in all C++ versions?

Comment: Comment 2 in the link seem to suggest it's invalid, but the error message is bad. Not sure where to look up the DR 2237, [diff.cpp17.class]p2 references.

Comment: @康桓瑋 So this means that `Rational<T>();` is valid in C++11, C++14 and C++17 but not in C++20 & onwards, right?

Comment: @Richard. From [diff.cpp17#class-2](https://eel.is/c++draft/diff.cpp17#class-2): "*Valid C++ 2017 code may fail to compile in this revision of C++.*"